# Populate Account on Opportunity using externalID in before insert Trigger

Tags: trigger, opportunity, account, externalid

I am to trying to populate Account lookup on Opportunity using External Id field on Opportunity using before insert trigger. It is not working however if I do it by a simple class it work. ID__c is my ExternalId field on Account.

```
trigger ExternalIdTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
        opp.Account = new Account(ID__c = '12321');
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Account(ID__c = '12321')` you are passing new account not that account id

Comment: ID__c is my external Id field on Account record.and trying to populate Account on Opportunity using it

Comment: First you need to query Account based on your external id then assinge the Account id to the opportunity id

Comment: Ratan is right. You can only apply the pattern you specified during an upsert, outside the trigger

Answer (score 1):

First you need to query Account based on external Id i.e. `12321`

```
trigger ExternalIdTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

  List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE ID__c = '12321'];

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
        if(!lstAccount.isEmpty())
        {
             opp.AccountId = lstAccount[0].Id;
        }
    }
}
```